# Polyglots for theoretical research like what is usage and definition

Tags: discussion

I asked about a test for what is a polyglot i.e. valid code in many programming languages. I got the comment "compile it" and OK I understand but do you have a more serious comment or also for strange reasons consider this "not a real question"? Are polyglots not worthy your opinion when I think it can be very advantages to have a format such as JSON that is valid in many languages.

Thanks for any comment / answer

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking this question here. Isn't such a question better suited for stackoverflow ? this is for research-level questions in theoretical computer science.

Comment: Also please read the [FAQ](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/faq) to understand cstheory's scope.

Comment: Isn't how you define a polygot cs research? I think it is.